# In PureMVC, should Proxies send Notifications themselves, or do so via the ApplicationFacade?

Tags: actionscript, flex3, puremvc

In the [PureMVC](http://puremvc.org) framework, Proxies communicate with the ApplicationFacade (and thus any interested components) via a Notification.  Should this Notification be sent via their own instance, or the Singleton instance of the ApplicationFacade?  Frankly, does it matter?

Here are two ways of doing this (in Flex/AS):

```
// from the proxy itself
this.sendNotification(ApplicationFacade.NOTIFY_ALL);

// via the ApplicationFacade instance
ApplicationFacade.getInstance().notifyObservers(new Notification(ApplicationFacade.NOTIFY_ALL));
```

The second method looks more verbose and less intuitive to me.  Moreover, the Proxy has the ability to send Notifications, which, in my mind, means it probably *should*.  Are there instances where the Proxy should only send a Notification via the ApplicationFacade instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `notifyObservers` function is part of an older implementation; the `sendNotification` call from the proxy is the acceptable method. Pretty sure that the notify function is just for backwards compatibility. Actually (just poked into the code): the `sendNotification` method of a class that implements `INotifier` merely calls `facade.sendNotification`, which, in turn, calls `facade.notifyObservers`, so the second method is the same as the first - it's just more verbose as you pointed out. So, yeah: first!